# Wordpress CSS I added just before the end of head does not override CSS that came from a linked style sheet

Tags: wordpress

I am using a custom theme called BETheme by Muffin Builder on my site.

There is one particular thing I would like to override and so I added CSS to that and the CSS appears right at the end of the header like this:

```
    theme css links in here
    <link rel='stylesheet' id='mfn-responsive-css' href='https://example.com/wp-content/themes/betheme/css/responsive.css?ver=21.2.9' type='text/css' media='all'/>
    theme css links in here 

    <style type="text/css" id="wp-custom-css">#Top_bar{background-color:#07052d!important}</style>
```

But whatever I do, when I inspect then the CSS from responsive.css is being acted on instead of my CSS.

When I look at the inspector here is what I see where this CSS is the one that is controlling what happens:

```
https://example.com/wp-content/themes/betheme/css/responsive.css?ver=21.2.9
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px)
.tr-menu.header-classic #Top_bar:not(.is-sticky) {
    top: 0!important;
    background-color: transparent!important;
}
```

further down in the Google Chrome developer inspector I see my CSS with a line across it appear.

Does anyone have any ideas why this could be? Why is the very last line not overriding the higher up CSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In CSS there are Specificity rules which govern how CSS precedence is applied to elements that are targeted by multiple CSS rules. For more details see [Specificity](https://developermozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity).

If you match the theme's style rule (so the specificity will be the same), and your CSS declaration follows the theme's, yours should apply:

```
.tr-menu.header-classic #Top_bar:not(.is-sticky) {
     background-color:#07052d!important;
}
```